# Как отобразить динамически изменяемый объект?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

У меня есть

```
<pe:fluidGridItem type="select" styleClass="select">  
<p:selectOneMenu id="IONodeWidget".../>
```

и

```
<pe:fluidGridItem type="select" styleClass="select"><p:autoComplete id="IOItemWidget"...
```

мне нужно вывести между ними сообщение в том случае если количество айтемов в `autoComplete` превышает определенное число.
 Я это задумала сделать так:

```
<pe:fluidGridItem style="margin-top:4px;color:red"><h:outputText id="errorMessage" value="#{myBean.outputTextValue}" escape="false"/>
```

По идее изначально `outputText` должен быть со значением `= " "`, а затем

```
 if (someList >= 5) {setOutputText("error")}
```

но при  этом компонент на форме не меняется.
Как передать этому компоненту новое значение??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предполагая, что *someList* это свойство некого бина *SomeBean*:

`rendered = "#{yourBean.someList >= 5}"`

где *rendered* это общий атрибут тегов из *JavaServer Faces standard HTML tag library*.

Подробнее можно посмотреть [Expression Language](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-el.htm#GJDDD) и [JSF standart HTML tag library](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-page002.htm#BNARF).

**Update:** Атрибут *rendered* принимает *javax.el.ValueExpression* (результатом которого будет `boolean`):

- Если выражение `true`, то компонент отображается на странице
- Если выражение `false` - компонент не отображается

Если в Вашем случае *someList* - список айтемов, который приходит из контроллера, то можно поступить следующим образом: в контроллере "положить" этот список в качестве атрибута запроса

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
request.setAttribute("someList", someList);
```

после чего до него можно добраться так

`#{request.getAttribute("someList")}`

где *request* - это **Implicit Object** (проще говоря *HttpServletRequest*). Соответственно, тег для нужного Вам сообщения будет выглядеть примерно так (я использую JSF HTML теги)

```
<h:outputText rendered="#{request.getAttribute(\"someList\") != null && 
                          request.getAttribute(\"someList\") >= 5} ...">
    Your message
</h:outputText>
```

Comment: someList - это список айтемов, который приходит из контроллера.  я не знаю как работает атрибут `rendered`. Можешь рассказать подробнее пожалуйста?

Comment: @DianaMeissen, я обновил ответ.

Comment: не получается зарендерить. Во-первых ругается на имя, а точнее на кавычки ". Попробовала без них request.getAttribute(someList), но толку особо нет.  Появляется `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0` . Отсюда следует вопрос переменная request должна быть глобальной?

Comment: @DianaMeissen, ругается на кавычки, потому что они используются и в атрибуте `rendered=""` и в выражении `#{""}`. Компилятор не понимает какие кавычки открываются, а какие закрываются (следующую кавычку он считает за конец строки). Для того, чтобы указать кавычки внутри кавычек... нужно написать так `"#{request.getAttribute(\"someList\")"`, можете еще попробовать `"#{request.getAttribute('someList')}`.

Comment: @DianaMeissen, переменная `request` это, скажем так, не Ваша забота :) **Веб контейнер гарантирует Вам доступ к ней**. Иными словами, она не должна быть не глобальной, ни локальной, никакай. Вы не обязаны создавать объект `request`.

Comment: получилось, спасибо за шикарный ответ) только вот когда появляется поле с ошибкой, то `autoComplete` превращается просто в лист айтемов и отображается (как и ошибка) справа от `selectOneMenu`. Хотя указаны параметры `style="margin-top:7px; color:red"` есть идеи почему так?